# XLSXwriter - writing multiple nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to write a multi-nested dictionary to an Excel file. The dictionary is structured as `dict1:{dict2:{dict3:value}}}`. My third write loop is raising a `keyerror: ''` even though there ought not be any blank keys.

I attempted to use this abhorrent monster as it has worked wonderfully for smaller dictionaries, but 1) there has to be a better way 2) I'm unable to scale it for this dictionary...

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('datatest.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('test1')                            
row = 0
col = 0
for key in sam_bps.keys():
    row += 1
    worksheet.write(row, col, key)
    for key in sam_bps[sam].keys():
        row, col = 0,1
        worksheet.write(row,col,key)
        row += 1
        for key in sam_bps[sam][bp].keys():
            row,col = 0,2
            worksheet.write(row,col,key)
            row += 1
            for key in sam_bps[sam][bp][mpn].keys():
                row,col = 0,3
                worksheet.write(row,col,key)
                row += 1
                for item in sam_bps[sam][bp][mpn].keys():
                    row,col = 0,4
                    worksheet.write(row,col,item)
                    row += 1
workbook.close()
```

I've also considered converting the dictionary to a list of tuples or list of lists, but it doesn't output how I need. And it'll probably cost more time to split those open afterwards anyway.

Here's the code for the dicionary:

```
sam_bps = {}
sam_bps_header = ['SAM','BP','MPN','PLM_Rate']
for row in plmdata:
    sam,mpn,bp,doc = row[24],row[5],row[7],row[2]
    if sam == '':
        sam = 'Unknown'
    if doc == 'Requirement':
        if sam not in sam_bps:
            sam_bps[sam] = {bp:{mpn:heatscores[mpn]}}
        elif bp not in sam_bps[sam]:
            sam_bps[sam][bp] = {mpn:heatscores[mpn]}
        elif mpn not in sam_bps[sam][bp]:
            sam_bps[sam][bp][mpn] = heatscores[mpn]
print(sam_bps['Dan Reiser'])
```

EDIT: Added print statement to show output per feedback

> {'Fortress Solutions': {'MSM5118160F60JS': 45}, 'Benchmark Electronics': {'LT1963AES8': 15}, 'Axxcss Wireless Solutions Inc': {'MGA62563TR1G': 405}}

I'd like to see this output to an Excel file, with the first column of course being the first key of `sam_bps`

Answer (score 0):

Your question would be easier to answer if you provided an example of the dictionary you are trying to save.

Have you considered just serializing/deserializing the dictionary to JSON format?

you can save/re-load the file with minimal code:

```
import json
data = {'test': {'test2': {'test3':2}}}
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)

with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

Comment: Added an example output underneath the dictionary code, I think that's what you asked for lol.
I hadn't considered using JSON format, simply because I hardly ever use it! I'll give this a shot though.

Comment: Alright, serializng as JSON was wonderfully simply. Connecting that JSON file to my Excel workbook is proving to be infinitely more difficult...